# Separate new filename and input into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

This code work good in making separate name and put their new name into database if the form is full submitted. The error is:

When I submit empty form:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 38
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 38

When I submit which just input file 1 has the photo it says (the photo 1 moved into upload folder):

> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 38
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 42
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 45
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 47
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 47
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 38

When I submit which just input file 2 has the photo it says (the photo 2 not moved into upload folder):

> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 38
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 38
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 42
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 45
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 47
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpE539.tmp' to 'upload/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 47

When I put submit 2 photo, both is moved into upload folder but still have error:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 38
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 42
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 45
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 47
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 47
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 38
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\cobas\create.php on line 42

Here is my code:

```
define( 'MAX_ALLOWED_FILE_SIZE', 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5Mb
define( 'UPLOAD_PATH', 'upload' );

function is_allowed_file_ext( $filename = null )
{
    $allowed_ext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $_parts = explode( '.', $filename );
    $_ext = end( $_parts );
    $_ext = strtolower( $_ext );
    if( in_array( $_ext , $allowed_ext ) ){
        return $_ext;
    }
    return false;
}

if( !empty( $_FILES['photo'] ) ){
    foreach ($_FILES['photo']['name'] as $key[] => $filename ) {
        if( $_FILES['photo']['error'][$key] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){

            if( $file_ext = is_allowed_file_ext( $filename ) ){
                $new_filename[] = sprintf( '%d-%s.%s', round(microtime(true)), uniqid(), $file_ext );
                if( $_FILES['photo']['size'][$key] <= MAX_ALLOWED_FILE_SIZE ){
                    // Everything is okay now, save the file                   
                    $dest_path[0] = sprintf( '%s/%s', rtrim(UPLOAD_PATH,'/'), $new_filename[0] );
                    $dest_path[1] = sprintf( '%s/%s', rtrim(UPLOAD_PATH,'/'), $new_filename[1] );                    
                    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key[0]], $dest_path[0] );
                    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key[1]], $dest_path[1] );

                }else{
                    $photo_errors[] = 'Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.';
                }
            }else{
                $photo_errors[] = $filename . ' is not a valid image';
            }
        }else{
            switch ( $_FILES['photo']['error'][$key] ) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                    $photo_errors[] = 'No file sent';
                    break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                    $photo_errors[] = 'Max file size exceeded!';
                    break;
                default:
                    $photo_errors[] = 'Unknown errors';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    $photo_errors[] = 'No photos selected';
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO employees (name, address, salary, code, photo, photo2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? , ?, ?)";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $param_name, $param_address, $param_salary, $asd, $new_filename[0] , $new_filename[1]);
```

Comment: can you provide an example of what you have so far and what you want to accomplish ?

Comment: first, i'm trying to make 2 input file type with new file name which is using microtime and uniqid then upload into upload folder, it's work.
now i'm trying to get the value in that 2 new file name, so i can put into database that 2 newfile name. I think it will be using array in newfilename but i'm so confused right now can u help me. Thx @Taki

Comment: srry, i mean 2 input file type with 2 new file name, and the code is work the upload folder has 2 different file name. now how i can get the 2 new file name value. Thx @Taki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
foreach ($_FILES['photo']['name'] as $key => $filename ) { // keep the $key ( not $key[] )
```

then :

```
if( $file_ext = is_allowed_file_ext( $filename ) ){
    $new_filename[$key] = sprintf( '%d-%s.%s', round(microtime(true)), uniqid(), $file_ext );
    if( $_FILES['photo']['size'][$key] <= MAX_ALLOWED_FILE_SIZE ){
    // Everything is okay now, save the file                   
    $dest_path[$key] = sprintf( '%s/%s', rtrim(UPLOAD_PATH,'/'), $new_filename[$key] );

    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key], $dest_path[$key] );

}
```

then :

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $param_name, $param_address, $param_salary, $asd, $new_filename[0], $new_filename[1]);
```

Comment: it work but, i'm trying to input newfilename not the original file name

Comment: @AnggaSuwito i edited my answer according to your comment, i hope this works for you